# Global Anti-Forgery Token validation issues

Tags: asp.net-core

I followed the code in this link in my Core 2.2 web app
[Global Antiforgery Token Validation in ASP.NET Core](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/global-antiforgery-token-validation-in-asp-net-core)

It works great. However, I now need to be able to exclude certain actions from running in this middleware.  I was thinking I could create an attribute to put on the methods I'd like to exclude and only run the validation if it's a POST request (as it does now) AND my new attribute is not on the action.  However, I can't figure out how I could check for the existence of an attribute within this middleware.  And maybe that's not even the best way to do it so I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply disable the validation of anti-forgery tokens for an action by applying the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute  :

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(customModel model)
```

For your idea , it is too early to know whether custom attribute is applying to current route in middleware .

**Update :**

You don't need to use middleware , you can add the recommended global filter `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` to protect POST method by default :

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

})
```

And in specific action add to `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` override global or controller antiforgery attributes . See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatically-validate-antiforgery-tokens-for-unsafe-http-methods-only) .

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  The automatic anti-forgery validation is still firing and still returning that the token is missing.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly.